# Avoiding blank space as an input in go

Tags: arrays, go

I am new to golang and have switched from python. I am trying to scan an array and display it back to the user. However if there are any trailing spaces go will not wait for the user to type the next int (as it happens in c++) but will instead use zero.

```
func main() {
    var k int
    fmt.Scanf("%d", &k)
    for i:= 0 ; i< k ; i++{
        arr(5)
    }
}
func arr(l int){
    arr:= make([]int, l)
    for i := 0; i < l; i++ {
        fmt.Scanf("%d",&arr[i])
    }
    fmt.Println(arr)
}
```

This is my code so when I enter

1_

1_2_3_4_5_
where underscore represents a black space it will print out

`[0 1 2 3 4]`

The expected result is

`[1 2 3 4 5]`

Is there something wrong with my code? Or is this just how the Scanf() function works and if so should what should I use so that it works similar to the c++ scanf()?
I tried to read about why this happens on my own and came across buffers but I didn't understand how that comes in the picture here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your output is a result of **ignoring errors** returned by `fmt.Scanf`.

With the input you showed the first call to `fmt.Scanf` inside `arr()` will return:
`0` and  `unexpected newline`.

The first value is the number of items successfully scanned. The second is the error returned. Because there is an error, `arr[0]` is not assigned anything and remains at the default value of `0`. Since you are ignoring the error, the program continues to `arr[1]` and will scan `1` from the next line.

The error comes from the fact that **newlines in the input need to match newlines in the format string**, per the [fmt.Scanf](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Scanf) docs.

To properly handle the first line, you should have something like the following:

```golang
func main() {
    var k int
    n, err := fmt.Scanf("%d\n", &k)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    if n != 1 {
        panic("expected one input")
    }
    for i:= 0 ; i< k ; i++{
        arr(5)
    }
}
```

You will similarly need to handle newlines in `arr()`.

---

Two pieces of advice:

- never ignore errors
- read the documentation for the functions you use

Comment: Hey thanks it works fine now. However I was trying to use this in a coding competition where the test cases have a blank space at the end. Is there any other function that I can use that will work like the c++ scanf() ?

Comment: It works just fine with a trailing space, that wasn't the problem, the newline (and ignored error) was.

Comment: @mMarc I added `_, err := fmt.Scanf("%d", &arr[i])` however I am still getting the 0 there.  Should I update the code to what it is now?

Comment: The problem was the missing newline on the first `Scanf`, the format string needs to be `%d\n`. The fixed code is shown in my answer. For the `arr` function, you'll also need to handle the newline if you have more than one line.